# Reverse ordering XML data in WP7 dev

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have one question. I have found code for ordering xml nodes in windows phone 7 listbox:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("P*****.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                {
                    XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                    var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("person")
                                       orderby (string)c.Attribute("name")
                                       select new Person()
                                       {
                                           Name = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                           Beneficiary = c.Attribute("beneficiary").Value,
                                           Price = c.Attribute("price").Value,
                                           Deadline = c.Attribute("deadline").Value,
                                           Index = c.Attribute("index").Value,
                                           Description = c.Attribute("description").Value,
                                           Status = c.Attribute("status").Value

                                       };

                    listBox.ItemsSource = filteredData;
                }
            }
```

But it's only work for ordering like from A to Z. But what I should do to order data in reverse ( from Z to A name) ? I have found something like this:

```
var people = data.Elements("person").OrderBy(p => (string)p.Attribute("Age"));
```

and changed it to :

```
var people = data.Elements("person").OrderBy(p <= (string)p.Attribute("Age"));
```

but it has error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So i think this method not make sense. Anyway, have you any idea for reverse XML ordering?

Comment: Have you tried `orderby (string)c.Attribute("name") descending` instead of `orderby (string)c.Attribute("name")`?

Answer (score 0):

You have found Linq!   this '=>'  reads as 'Goes to'   Which is why when you attempt to reverse it you get an error.

look here for examples http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-4